# Can I install Windows 64-bit on a computer that has an Intel Core 2 Duo processor?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, compatibility, intel-core2

I have an HP laptop with the following specs:

- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T5870 @ 2.00 GHz
- RAM: 2GB

I want to install atrial version of Adobe After Effects, but Adobe After Effects only runs on 64-bit Windows. Can I install Windows 64-bit on this computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have a 64-bit processor. You can install a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: you need driver support too

Comment: There are definitely 64-bit drivers for that computer. It's not old enough to not have them. HP was writing 64-bit drivers for old models when *Vista* was still in beta.

Comment: ok , I'm very happy to know that but which windows (xp, vista , windows 7), thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a choice, always choose Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 7 x64 should work fine for you. Also, windows license keys work for either the 32-bit or 64-bit version, so if you can find a 64-bit installation disk, you don't even need to buy a new license. You can't do an in-place upgrade though.

Answer (score 2):

Just for future reference the [manufacturers website](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37034/intel-core-2-duo-processor-t5870-2m-cache-2-00-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html) is usually your best bet to check feature compatibility.

Look for 'Instruction Set' to find out whether the hardware supports a 64-bit operating system version.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I have a good experience with running 64-bit versions of Windows 7 and Windows 10 on various Core 2 Duo/Quad CPUs (slot 775) on various chipsets for many years. Also old GPUs work without troubles (needed because these CPUs don't have integrated video), because operating system can use older drivers. The only real-world limitation is RAM size. 4 GB is possible but not good for 64-bit Windows 7/10, 6 GB is much better (2x 2GB + 1x 1GB DDR2 module).

And although internet is full of information that these old CPUs cannot run Windows 11, several people reported they actually can run W11, it is just not officially supported by Microsoft. (I did not tried myself.)